# <font> tag seems to be formatting footer div?

Tags: html

I am writing a contact form in PHP (this is a html question) and have used the `<font>` tags to change the size of text and even though I have used `</font>` as it was needed, the footer font has changed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpGHe.jpg
to
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtfkZ.jpg

I do not know a lot of HTML and the size changing made me believe it is the  tag I used.

How can I change the size of the text in the second link back to the default size in the first?

Comment: It might be a good idea to include the HTML you're asking about.

Comment: You're going to need to provide code in order for anybody to help you. Show your PHP code that generates the HTML. Show the HTML itself. Are you sure you're closing your font tag correctly? For what it's worth, nowadays CSS is preferred for setting font settings.

Comment: `font` tags are very much deprecated in favour of using CSS. Googling for "font size css" should get you the info you need. Or wait for somebody with more time than me to answer this with examples, etc. `font` tags should probably have worked though. If the resize is leaking outside of that tag then there is probably a syntax problem (eg unclosed font tag or similar).

Comment: The tag most likely isn't close correctly, even though you indicated that it has.

Comment: The upvote baffles me; there's not enough information here to make it a complete, let alone good, question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Wrapping your Form in a:

```
<div style="font-size: #px;">
CODE
</div>
```

instead of a font tag. This is a cleaner way and separates the item out from the rest. May not be the best of explanations, but seems to work for me most of the time.

Comment: Thanks, Worked great! A lot simpler than the other answers (though, thanks all for trying :) ) and worked perfectly! :D

Answer (score 0):

The `<font>` tag is deprecated. You are probably best off using the `<span>` tag with the `style` attribute, or ideally using CSS.

For example, you might have something like this:

```
<body style="font-size:14px">
```

Which means all the text in your page will default to 14 pixels.

Then for 'special' text, you could do this:

```
<span style="font-size:12px;color:red">some text</span>
```

Alternatively you could use a CSS `class` which would like this:

```
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-size:14px;
}
span {
    color:blue;
}
.myClass {
    font-size:12px;
    color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Here is some text that has <span>different parts</span> to it including some <span class="myClass">color and size</span>variation.
```

Comment: Follow up comment, depending on the PHP, if you are generating the HTML dynamically, the inline styling (`<span style="font....">`) may be easier to write for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation but WardsParadox's answer is a lot simpler and worked perfectly :)

Comment: @user3798369 Divs are used for positioning and Spans are used for styling. If you need both -> use a Div. But if you are just styling text inside a div -> use a span.